# PhpUnit 10 assert error about configuration

Tags: phpunit

I have upgraded PhpUnit from 9 to 10 and now im getting an error I don't understand.

assert(self::$instance instanceof Configuration)

Im looping thru a list of test files:

```
foreach ($testClasses as $name) {
    $suite = PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::fromClassName($name);
```

And each test case is like:
`class TestAllocine extends TestCase {`

Can someone please explain what this means?

Php 8.2

Comment: What is the exact error? I would expect `$this->assertTrue(self::$instance instanceof Configuration);`.

Comment: This is the error message: "assert(self::$instance instanceof Configuration)"

Comment: That is the complete output? Nothing more?